# Symfony 4 optional locale/prefix only for one domain route

Tags: symfony, routes, locale, symfony4, prefix

I'm trying to create prefix for only one domain in Symfony 4.

I would like to have following domains:

```
domain1.com
domain1.pl
domain2.com
**domain2.com/pl**
```

**First option, I have tried**

In `/config/routes/annotations.yaml`:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
controllers_localized:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        pl: /pl
        en: /
```

But it adds to all domains prefixes and I want prefix only for `domain2.com` > `domain2.com/pl`

**Second option, I have tried**

In `/config/routes.yaml` route to the same controller:

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index
index_localized:
    path: /{_locale}
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index
    defaults:
        path: /pl
        permanent: true
careers_localized:
    path:
        en: /careers
        pl: /{_locale}/kariera
    defaults:
        path: /pl
        permanent: true
    controller: App\Controller\CareersController::careers
```

It works, but I have to change all anchors/link hrefs with if conditions in twig templates with additional `/pl` and add all Route cases in yaml which is time-consuming.

I wouldn't like to use bundles which was suggested for older Symfony versions